# How can set an image on the another image?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

how can get image from gallery and set this image on another image and edit this image for fix this on frist image??
(Sorry for my weak english language)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it currently stands, your question could be more clear. Adding context, code you've already tried, and an indication of where you are at in tackling the problem will all help people answer you better.

Comment: Tnx for your help, but i dont know how i can do it

Comment: Are you trying to program an Android app? Are you trying to find an app to merge two images on your personal Android device? You're also asking several questions here, which would be best asked individually: How do you select an image from the gallery (this question has answers already)? How do you "set this image on another image"? How do you "edit this image for fix on first image"?

Comment: Yes i trying to create an android app and i want to get an image from gallery( i know how i can do this) and merge with another image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only want to display two overlapped images in UI try to use FrameLayout

[how to overlap two images each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332015/how-to-overlap-two-images-each-other)

but if you really want to combine those images you can  do that through 'Canvas' class

[How to combine multiple images into a single image in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151937/how-to-combine-multiple-images-into-a-single-image-in-android)
http://www.jondev.net/articles/Combining_2_Images_in_Android_using_Canvas

Comment: Tanks tanks taaaaaaanks my feriend